# How to increase the requests/sec during executing Performance Test using JMeter

Tags: httprequest, jmeter, performance-testing

How to increase the request/sec in JMeter? I tried to increase thread group count to 150 and ramp-up is 10, still I got 6 req/sec.

Is there any other way to increase the req/sec? Please help me.

Thanks in Advance
Venkat

Answer (score 0):

To generate higher rate you'll need more threads in thread group. And if your service degrades (becomes slower and slower while request rate increases), you'll need even more active threads to generate requests.

See also this: http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer

Comment: can u please tell me the figure of more active threads approximately ?

Comment: see the link, there is formula